# I have a quiz with a few hundred questions. How do I make the questions and answers available to SEO?

Tags: google-search

With the normal flow, each user sees 1 question at a time, answers it using a POST request and moves to the next question.

I don't think search engines will do POST operations. How do I get my questions indexed using the url of the quiz?

So the URL of the quiz is '/quiz' and clicking on the "Take Quiz" button will do a POST and display the 1st question. The user will select an answer and click "Next" which will show the next question and so on.

I want to have my questions indexed but under the /quiz URL.

I can put them in a hidden div, but that may be considered cheating.

Comment: You can't expect to get them indexed, search and find question #10 and then land on the first question.      Search engines want people to see the content the searched for when the landing page first loads.   If that doesn't happen it will kill your rankings.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect Googlebot to complete the POST action.

I think you have two primary options:

1. On question one, link to question #2. This will essentially allow users to see the next question without posting an answer to the first one.
2. Add your question URLs to your sitemap. Google may not crawl the form POST on your quiz, but it likely will crawl your sitemap especially if it thinks that your domain is important.

I wouldn't add hidden links to the quiz pages. Google will see that they are hidden when rendering the page and this could hit you.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, we cannot expect google to do want we want. We can only suggest, not insist.

Regarding your question, one way is to have those questions in a format that google seems to love. For example, who is, what are, is it possible, when was, when is, how to, how can I, etc. You can see these patterns when you begin typing a question in the search bar, and the google autofill takes over to suggest completions.

Then, if it's possible, list all the questions in a dedicated page which google can crawl at once. And then add it to your sitemap. I also like the idea by Michael d, of creating a "linked list" of questions.

Finally, Google seems to love HTML markup that uses lists and tables for questions and information -- those are what you see in featured snippet boxes in Google search results. Here are some more details: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/featured-snippets-types/219907/